# Django TypeError: allow_migrate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_name'

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I copied over my Django project to a new server, replicated the environment and imported the tables to the local mysql database.

But when I try to run makemigrations it gives me the TypeError: allow_migrate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_name'

This is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
self.check()
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1266, in check
errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1337, in _check_fields
errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 893, in check
errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 208, in check
errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 310, in _check_backend_specific_checks
if router.allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=self.model._meta.model_name):
File "/home/cicd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 300, in allow_migrate
allow = method(db, app_label, **hints)
TypeError: allow_migrate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_name'
```

I would appreciate any help in debugging this error and trying to understand what is causing this error.

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#signature-of-the-allow-migrate-router-method. Which version of Django are you using on your new server?

Comment: yea so I did move from 1.9.4 to 1.10, but should that cause this, because this feature change that you linked is from 1.8 to 1.9

Comment: And downgrading to 1.9.4 fixed the issue, thanks elethan. But I am still wondering why?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure why. Maybe you had some compiled Django files (`.pyc` files) left around from the older version? You might try cleaning up your `.pyc` files and trying 1.10 again, but I don't know if it would make a difference.

Comment: You might actually try upgrading to 1.10 again without making any other changes. It looks like `allow_migrate()` doesn't take a `model_name` argument in 1.10 *or* 1.9.4, which makes have had some  outdated `.pyc` files on your server, and maybe the downgrade flushed them out. Just speculation, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: Note that the old signature for `allow_migrate()` linked by elethan was deprecated in 1.8. If you run that code on 1.9 with the `-Wall` option, you should see a deprecation warning, but the old signature will still work. It was properly removed in 1.10, which explains the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 11):

I meet the same problem when i move from 1.6.* to 1.10.Finally i found the problem cause by the **DATABASE_ROUTERS**

the old version i write like this

```
class OnlineRouter(object):
    # ... 
    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        if db == 'myonline':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'online'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'online':
            return False
        return None
```

it work by rewrite like this

```
class OnlineRouter(object):
    # ... 
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if db == 'my_online':
            return app_label == 'online'
        elif app_label == 'online':
            return False
        return None
```

more detail see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example